# How list's Find(s) method works in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Which is the best way to loop thru an list? is for loop better than numerous List class's find method? Also if i use its find methed as i mentioned below which is anonymous delegate an instance of an predicate delegate, does it better than using lambda expression? Which one will execute faster?

```
var result = Books.FindLast(
        delegate(Book bk)
        {
            DateTime year2001 = new DateTime(2001,01,01);
            return bk.Publish_date < year2001;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **complex** question because it involves a lot of different topics.

In general, delegates are many times slower than a simple function call but to enumerate a list (via foreach) is terribly slow too.

If you really care about performance (but do not do it a-priori, profile!) you should avoid delegates and enumerations. First big step (whenever possible) could be to use a Hashtable instead of a *simple* list.

### Examples

Now some examples, I'll write the same function in different ways, from the more readable (but slower) to the less readable (but faster). I omit every error checking but a real world function shouldn't (at least some asserts are required).

This function uses LINQ, it's the more easy to understand but the slowest.
Note the `books` can be a generic enumeration (it's not required to be a `List<T>`)

```
public static Book FindLastBookPublishedBefore(IEnumerable<Book> books, 
                                               DateTime date)
{
 return books.FindLast(x => x.Publish_date < date);
}
```

Same as before but without LINQ. Note that this function
handles a special case: the list doesn't contains any eligible book.

```
public static Book FindLastBookPublishedBefore(IEnumerable<Book> books,
                                               DateTime date)
{
 Book candidate = null;
 foreach (Book book in books)
 {
  if (candidate == null || candidate.Publish_date > book.Publish_date)
   candidate = book;
 }

 return candidate;
}
```

Same as before but without enumeration, note that this function
handles a special case: the list doesn't contains any eligible book.

```
public static Book FindLastBookPublishedBefore(List<Book> books,
                                               DateTime date)
{
 Book candidate = null;
 for (int i=0; i < books.Count; ++i)
 {
  if (candidate == null || candidate.Publish_date > books[i].Publish_date)
   candidate = books[i];
 }

 return candidate;
}
```

Same as before but with a `SortedList<T>` as suggested by @MaratKhasanov. Please note that with this container you'll have the good performances during the search but insertion of a new element can be more slow than a *normal* unsorted list (because list itself must be kept sorted). If the number of elements in the list is **very high** you may think to write your own sorted list using a `Hashtable` (using, for example, the year as key for the first level).

```
public static Book FindLastBookPublishedBefore(SortedList<Book> books,
                                               DateTime date)
{
 Book candidate = null;
 for (int i=0; i < books.Count; ++i)
 {
  DateTime publishDate = books[i].Publish_date;

  if (publishDate > date)
   return candidate;

  if (candidate == null || candidate.Publish_date > publishDate)
   candidate = books[i];

 }

 return candidate;
}
```

Now an example a little bit more complex but with **best** search performance. Algorithm is derived from an ordinary [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) (note that if you want to match the first element that matches the predicate you may use the [List.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4e7fxsh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method directly).
Note that code is untested and can be optimized too, please consider it just an example.

```
public static Book FindLastBookPublishedBefore(List<Book> books,
                                               DateTime date)
{
 int min = 0, max = books.Count;
 Book candidate = null;

 while (min < max)
 {
  int mid = (min + max) / 2;
  Book book = books[mid];

  if (book.Publish_date > date)
   max = mid - 1;
  else
  {
   candidate = book;
   ++min;
  }

  if (min >= max)
   break;
 }

  return candidate;
}
```

Before moving to a more complex container you may think to keep your `SortedList<T>` unsorted until the first search. It'll be really slow (because it will sort the list too) but inserts will be as fast as a normal list (but you have to try with real world data). Anyway last algorithm can be optimized a lot.

Maybe if you have so many items in your collection that you can't manage them with a *normal* collection you may think to move everything to a database...lol

Comment: I also would recommend to look at SortedList for this kind of search

Comment: @MaratKhasanov yes, you're right. I think the choice of the right container depends on the context, if search speed is very important and he can sacrifice insertion speed then the SortedList is very good.

Answer (score 2):

Use whatever makes your code more readable. You can simplify the code above by using lambda expressions; they are just a simplified syntax for anonymous delegates. Wherever you can use delegates you can use lambda expressions or normal methods. You would pass a normal method as argument without parentheses.

The C# compiler really just makes a hidden method for anonymous delegates and lambda expressions. You will probably not experience any difference in speed.

```
var result = Books.FindLast(bk => bk.Publish_date < new DateTime(2001,01,01));
```